# Delay when using openURL right after after app launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplication, openurl

I am trying to launch another application using its **url handler** right on my own app launch.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{        
     NSURL *actionURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fantastical2://"];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:actionURL];
}
```

It basically works, however there is a significant delay of about 7 seconds from seeing my app appear to actually opening the URL.

How come the delay? How can I launch open a URL/app immediately when launching my own app or reduce this delay?

Comment: Try with the NSTimer with target ..

Comment: Perfect. That works. Thanks a lot. Would you add that comment as answer then I can mark it accordingly.

Comment: Welcome ... Just added for officially ...

Comment: I think this is better asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19356488/1362154)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the NSTimer with target ..

For just Reference :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];


 -(void) targetMethod{
    // Call Here ...
     NSURL *actionURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fantastical2://"];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:actionURL];

    //Invalidate the time
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
 }
```

Comment: I also noticed that the time interval shouldn't be 0.0 even when I want to call the method immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You can resolve using any of the examples below.

## Using diapatch_async

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlString];
});
```

## Using perfomSelector

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  ...

  //hangs for 10 seconds
  //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];

  //Fix: use threads!
  [self performSelector:@selector(redirectToURL:)
      withObject:url afterDelay:0.0];

  ...
}

- (void)redirectToURL:(NSString *)url
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

## Using NSThread

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  ...

  //hangs for 10 seconds
  //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];

  //Fix: use threads!
  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(openBrowserInBackground:)
      toTarget:self withObject:url];

  ...
}

- (void)openBrowserInBackground:(NSString *)url
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your code in `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` because `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` will be called after `applicationDidFinishLaunching` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `-openURL` method within a block that runs on the main thread.  This will cause it to execute once everything else is loaded:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSURL *actionURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fantastical2://"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:actionURL];
    });
}
```